# What qualities have led to the enduring popularity of The Legend of Sleepy Hollow?

Tags: short-stories, history-of-literature, washington-irving

The short story The Legend of Sleepy Hollow by Washington Irving has remained extremely popular. Wikipedia lists 24 film and TV adaptations including the well known Tim Burton film and, perhaps more unsurprisingly, 19 musical works inspired by the story.

It is not long and [available in the public domain](https://gutenberg.org/ebooks/41) if you want to read it. I have just done so and was surprised to find it very ordinary. The writing is charming but veers to the purple in places. And the tale itself is spun well enough but lacks anything in the way of originality.

First published in 1820 it thus shares an era with titans of gothic horror such as Shelley and Poe. They too, of course, enjoy ongoing fame: but their imagination and originality would seem to warrant it.

What qualities does Sleepy Hollow have that it has remained so popular alongside them?

Comment: A love triangle, a wild ride and an ambiguous ending. A sketchy tale with plants of scope for scriptwriters to flex their skills and special effects designers to let rip, does it need more?

Comment: In case that seemed flippant, this is one of those questions that seems both interesting and deceptively simple. I’d like to see it answered, but don’t think I’m personally equipped to give anything more in depth. I had thought that the ‘wild ride’ was something of a trope as a theme for short dramatic pieces, (Tam O’Shanter, John Gilpin, Paul Revere, Man from Snowy River, How they Brought the Good News from Ghent to Aix etc) but can find nothing quotable on the subject.

Comment: I'm interested to see the answer to this question, as I read this story in 6th grade English and found it long (for a short story) and dreadfully boring. However, an interesting thought would be how accurate those movie/TV adaptations are...